# Git remote end hung up unexpectedly after push and new remote added

Tags: git, github, git-push

In my code-base, I added a remote configuration and attempted to upload an existing project by the following command line entries:

```
user@xubuntu: git remote add origin https://github.com/USER/PROJECT.git
user@xubuntu: /var/www/mywebsite$ sudo git push -u origin master
```

I get the following response:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I tried using BitBucket but I get the same error.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Before trying to upload an existing project, try creating a new project on github and then try cloning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably configure your git config to user your name and email that you login to github with. The reason you are getting the error is because you have not setup your public key.

https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 0):

You should push your public key to remote server and get the authority!